# Measuring integration test coverage with Maven

Tags: java, code-coverage, integration-testing, maven, emma

The followings are ok now:

- I have a multi-module project in maven with EJB and WAR projects
- I want to use JMeter (and later selenium) for integration testing. I can run both from Maven. The JMeter plan is ready, I run it with Chronos maven plugin.
- My application is a Java EE application, so I want to test the code with the planned production aplication server, which is Glassfish 2.11. I can create/start/deploy/stop and anything like that with glassfish maven plugin
- I have put jmeter and glassfish related build settings into a submodule in maven, which is dependent on all of the other modules, so in build lifecycle it is the least, and for this reason a good point to test the whole application

My problem is, that how can I reach the followings:

- deploy NOT instrumented code, but run integration tests on instrumented one
- how to get coverage info from application server
- I wanted to use [emma4it](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/06/integration-tests-with-maven-part-2-test-coverage-reports/) which was created to instrument artifacts. It would be good for me, but i cannot make it instrument the war file in the other submodule. I do not even know anything about the supported arguments of emma4it, since I did not find it at all (just a binary in repository), no documentation and no source (I know I can decompile it)
- I want to have a coverage raport at least in maven site, but the top would be to have it in Sonar

Could you give me advice, how to do this? I can provide POM snippets if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINALLY. The solution arrived. See at http://www.sonarsource.org/measure-code-coverage-by-integration-tests-with-sonar/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+Sonar+(Sonar)&utm_content=Google+Reader

I currently try to do it.